# mysql query with regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL table like this

```
restaurant_id   restaurant_name     restaurant_serving_cuisines
1               Vasantha Bhavan     4,5,6
3               Little India        7,5,6
5               Mohan Restaurants   16,2,4,1,5,3,6
6               Sri Restaurant      34,16,21,2,23,38,30,7,25,9
13              The Taco Shop       5
22              KFC                 15
37              belargio            14,15,16,2,7,4,1,5,17,12,3,13,6
56              Pizza Hot           5
```

I need to get the restaurant which is serving the cuisine id with 5 & 15.
I need to get the restaurant as belargio.

I am writing the query

```
SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name,restaurant_serving_cuisines 
FROM `rt_restaurant`
WHERE restaurant_serving_cuisines REGEXP concat_ws("|",    "5",    "15");
```

But I cant get the exact result.

Comment: If you have columns containing comma-separated lists of something you should check your data-model. restaurant_serving_cuisines should go to a separate table and there would be no need for regex at all.

Comment: regexp is probably overkill.  Look into the `LIKE` function or `FIND_IN_SET`.  (Besides being overkill, your example has the comma separated values NOT in a specified order.  You would at least need to guarantee an order for regexp to work)

Comment: Hello, I strongly recommend that you `NORMALIZE` restaurant_serving_cuisines column. Normalize can help you when you do COUNT, MAX, MIN, SORT, inserting new cuisines, update, delete and so on...

Answer (score 1):

How about using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name,restaurant_serving_cuisines 
FROM `rt_restaurant` 
WHERE find_in_set(5, restaurant_serving_cuisines) > 0
and find_in_set(15, restaurant_serving_cuisines) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`FIND_IN_SET` is good but too specific.

This should work for any DBMS:

```
SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name, restaurant_serving_cuisines 
FROM `rt_restaurant` 
WHERE ',' + restaurant_serving_cuisines + ',' LIKE '%,5,%'
  AND ',' + restaurant_serving_cuisines + ',' LIKE '%,15,%'
```

Anyway, you should probably check your data model, as already suggested:
`restaurant_serving_cuisines` should go to a separate table